# Minimizer of sum of convex combination of convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[The accepted answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866379/minimum-of-sum-of-strictly-convex-functions) is very close to yet still missed a bit to what I want to know. It gives an example where the minimizer of $f=f_1+f_2$ is not a convex combination of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$. However, what happens of $f$ itself is a convex combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (i.e., $f=\theta f_1 + (1-\theta) f_2$ where $0<\theta<1$)? Is the statement 'the minimizer of $f$ is a convex combination of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$' true then? Furthermore, could the statement 'the minimizer of $f$ is the weighted average of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$ weighted according to $\theta$ and $1-\theta$' be true (needless to say this is even harder to be true)? Finally, if neither of those two statement is true, my guess is the following statement has to be true: given d-dimensional convex functions $f_1,...,f_n$, and the coordinates of their respective minimizer $(m_{1,1},...,m_{1,d}),...,(m_{n,1},...,m_{n,d})$, the coordinates of the minimizer of the convex combination of $f_1,...,f_n$ is $(m_{1}^*,...,m_{d}^*)$ such that $ min_{i}\{m_{i,j}\} \leq m_{j}^*\leq max_{i}\{m_{i,j}\} \,\forall j \in [d]$. But I'm not sure how to prove it.

[The accepted answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983368/the-minimum-of-the-sum-of-two-convex-functions) is related to my last statement, but it considered sum of $f_1$ and $f_2$ instead of their convex combination.

Comment: If you take the example with $f=f_1+f_2$ and instead use $g=(1/2)(f_1+f_2)$, then $g$ is a convex combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$, and the minimizer of $g$ should be the same as the minimizer of $f$ and thus not a convex combination of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$, right?

Comment: Is my comment helpful, Sam?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes but I am not able to accept a comment.. I already upvoted

Comment: If you consider my comment to have answered your question (or at least part of it), you could encourage me to post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so can you post your comment as an answer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comment elevated to partial answer at suggestion of OP]

To answer part of the question: OP refers to an example where the minimizer of $f=f_1+f_2$ is not a convex combination of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$. If we let
$$
g={f_1+f_2\over2}
$$
then $g$ is a convex combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$, and the minimizer of $g$ is the same as the minimizer of $f$ and thus not a convex combination of the minimizers of $f_1$ and $f_2$.